# How to define a YouTube History Search Engine in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have defined a Search Engine in Google Chrome ("Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (64-bit)"):

[image]

But it does not work the way it should. Trying it out via:

```
yth automation
```

It goes to https://www.youtube.com/feed/history and not what I would have expected it to.

Now, if I then find the search field, on the above https://www.youtube.com/feed/history page, and type in "automation", and press the return key, I get a URL that I would have expected:

https://www.youtube.com/feed/history?query=automation

So how do I make this Quick Search to work as expected, which is **not** requiring me to do a two step operation, first to go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/history, and then type in the phrase in that field?  The whole point of quick searches are to save time and finger presses.